# Sum of positive semi-difinite matrix inequality

Tags: positive-semidefinite

Can the following conclusion hold?

---

There exist matrices $H^i\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, (m\leq n, i\in\mathcal{N})$, and non-zero real numbers $\underline{h}^i$, and $\overline{h}^i$.
If the following inequality holds 
\begin{align}
{\underline{h}^i}^2 I_{m}\leq H^{i} (H^{i})^T \leq {\overline{h}^i}^2 I_{m}
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i\in\mathcal{N}}(H^{i})^T H^{i} >0,  
\end{align}
then 
\begin{align}
 \sum_{i\in\mathcal{N}}(H^{i})^T H^{i} \geq \min_{i\in\mathcal{N}}\{{\underline{h}^i}^2\} I_n
\end{align}

---

Note: The expression matrix $M>0$ means matrix $M$ is positive definite. Similarly, the expression $A\geq B$ means $A-B$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: What does it mean for one matrix to be less than or equal to another matrix? Is $h$ a real number? Also, in the last line, what is the minimum being taken over?

Comment: Thanks for your questions. The descriptions have been updated such that all your concerns have been addressed.